# Command line args in ant

Tags: xml, command-line, ant, args

I have an ant build file that I want to pass arguments through like so:

ant command: `ant prob1 -Darg=Bob`

Where Darg is being set to "Bob".

I have it passed in like this in my xml file:

```
<target name="prob1">
        <java jar="build/jar/prob1.jar" fork="true">
                <arg value="$Darg"/>
```

But all I get out is "`$Darg`" as the argument that is passed in.  I am pretty sure I have something written wrong in my xml file but I am unsure what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to retrieve a variable is the following: `${var.name}`.

Thus you need to change your xml like this:

```
<arg value="${arg}"/>
```

since with the `-D` argument, you will set the `arg` variable.